# Formatting json properties

Tags: json, formatting

I have a JSON file with thousands of lines, which i need to have in another format.

My current code looks like that:

```
[{"Date":"2012-05-11","Value":19.5},
{"Date":"2012-05-15","Value":19.5},
{"Date":"2012-05-16","Value":18},
{"Date":"2012-05-17","Value":17.75},
...]
```

And it should look like this:

```
    [Date.UTC(2012,5,11),19.5],
    [Date.UTC(2012,5,13),19.5],
    [Date.UTC(2012,5,16),18],
    [Date.UTC(2012,5,17),17.75],
 ....]
```

Is there a tool or a quick way to do this, changing thousands of lines manually would take too much time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically, say php for instance, and treating each line of your JSON file as a string, you could use preg_replace(), but since it's a one time requirement, simply load your json file into a text editor and:

Delete the leading and ending square braces.

Find all  `{"Date":"`  replace with `[Date.UTC(`

Find all  `","Value":` replace with `),`

Find all `},` replace with `],`

Save

Comment: And if you know you don't have any dashes but those within the dates, you could find all `-` and replace with `,`